# how can i add css style to imported component in react

Tags: css, reactjs, components, styles

i have a menu component that want to have different background color in different pages.

How can i add css class to an imported component

I test code blow but didn't works

```
import Menu from './../Menu/Menu';
import "./menu.css"
.
.
.
<Menu className="menuBg"/>
```

Comment: try adding `!important` property

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline styling for that part

Comment: don't know why but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Make sure that in menu.css you have classes and not id. (And valid path to css file).

```
.thisIsClass {
  color: #000;
}
#thisIsID {
  color: #000;
}
```

Or try with !important.

```css
.thisIsClass {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

You can also direct add style to you div,

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: "#ff00ff", color: "#f00" }}>
```

EDIT:
You can't style Components direct, only parse props.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pass class as props to your component? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bhi95v

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
import Menu from './../Menu/Menu';
import style from "./menu.css";

<Menu className={style.menuBg}/>
```

Hope it helps!